# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException where getDeclaredMethods() shows otherwise

Tags: java, android, exception, reflection

My problem is simple.  So simple I can't seem to figure it out.  I am passing a qualified class name to a `BroadcastReceiver` as a `String` in an `Intent`.

The goal is to instantiate an object from the class name using reflection, and call a method which we know exists, because it implements a proprietary interface.  I am even checking it against `getDeclaredMethods()` which says its there, but when I try to `invoke` that method, it throws a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException`.

```
String myClass = intent.getStringExtra("name");        
Class<?> c = Class.forName(myClass);
Object object = c.newInstance();

// Get the files from the interface

Method ms[] = c.getDeclaredMethods();
for (Method m1 : ms) {
    Log.i("METHOD", "METHODS " + m1.getName());
}

Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getStrings", (Class<?>) null);
String[] someStrings = (String[]) m.invoke(object, (Object[]) null);

m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getThings", (Class<?>) null);
Thing[] things = (Thing[]) m.invoke(object, (Object[]) null);
```

Here is the LogCat output:

```
08-30 23:37:36.150: INFO/METHOD(2336): METHODS getStrings
08-30 23:37:36.150: INFO/METHOD(2336): METHODS getThings
08-30 23:37:36.150: WARN/System.err(2336): java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getStrings
08-30 23:37:36.150: WARN/System.err(2336):     at java.lang.ClassCache.findMethodByName(ClassCache.java:247)
08-30 23:37:36.150: WARN/System.err(2336):     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:731)
08-30 23:37:36.150: WARN/System.err(2336):     at com.app.MyBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(MyBroadcastReceiver.java:45)
08-30 23:37:36.150: WARN/System.err(2336):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1794)
08-30 23:37:36.150: WARN/System.err(2336):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-30 23:37:36.150: WARN/System.err(2336):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:981)
08-30 23:37:36.150: WARN/System.err(2336):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-30 23:37:36.160: WARN/System.err(2336):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-30 23:37:36.160: WARN/System.err(2336):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-30 23:37:36.160: WARN/System.err(2336):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-30 23:37:36.160: WARN/System.err(2336):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-30 23:37:36.160: WARN/System.err(2336):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-30 23:37:36.160: WARN/System.err(2336):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-30 23:37:36.160: WARN/System.err(2336):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is there something I am missing here?

Edit: Added the code to the class

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {

    @Override
    public String[] getStrings() {
        // Stub
        return new String[2];
    }

    @Override
    public Thing[] getThings() {
        // Stub
        return new Thing[2];
    }

}
```

Note: The `BroadcastReceiver` and the `Class` are in different projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

getDeclaredMethod requires you give the right parameters.  If there are no parameters, then instead of passing "null", you need to pass absolutely nothing.

For example, here is a code snippet for hashCode, which takes no arguments

```
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("hashCode");
System.out.println("test");
Method m2 = c.getDeclaredMethod("hashCode", (Class<?>) null);
```

it will print out "test", then throw a MethodNotFound exception as hashCode takes no arguments.  If you want to get the argument types as well as the name, execute the getParameterTypes on the method object

```
for (Method m1 : ms) {
    System.out.println( "METHODS " + m1.getName());
    for (Class paramC : m1.getParameterTypes()) {
        System.out.println(paramC.getName());
    }
    }
```

Comment: As Momo said down below, new Class[0] works better, though what would probably work best is for your to save a reference to the Method object as soon as you find the one you are looking for when you are iterating through the loop.  That way you are guaranteed to have a reference to the desired Method object no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

This might help.
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2812

Post a comment or edit your original post if its not the same, with more specifics. :)

The thread I linked above is about a bug with the platform causing others similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

Few possible reasons:

- Are you passing the right parameters in trying to get the declared method?
- If the method doesn't take any parameter, try passing new Class[0] instead of null

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're sending the correct parameters list in the getDeclaredMethod call.
Right now you're sending `(Class<?>) null`. What is the signature of the method getStrings?

Comment: It is a simple function with no arguments

Comment: Try transfering 'new Class[] {}' instead so that the call would be:
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getStrings", new Class[] {});

Answer (score -1):

there could be a couple of reasons for this, firstly, your src object may not be the one you thought it to be. Secondly, you might be trying to access a private member. Giving the code of this class u r instantiating would be great!

Comment: Trying to invoke a private method will generate a different exception than the one the OP got.  Namely it will generate a java.lang.IllegalAccessException, not a java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Comment: i know but i thought that this question is related to that issue to(though not exactly) and that this post should contain the general precautions to deal with when tackling such issues